# Ambiguous reference to member 'filter' swift4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have the list of following model class

```
struct CommonRes {
var month: String?
var monthName: String?
var year: String?
var classIdCount: String?
var groupName: String?
}
 var res = [CommonRes]()
```

In the response I am receiving the duplicate values of monthName. I want to make the list of these common monthName by removing duplicates. So from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727618/find-duplicate-elements-in-array-using-swift/35387247#35387247) I have tried the following

```
 self.monthList = Array(Set(res.filter({ (i : CommonRes) in res.filter({ $0.monthName == i.monthName }).count > 1 })))
```

But I am receiving an error

> Ambiguous reference to member 'filter'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
let monthList = Set(res.compactMap( {$0.monthName} )).sorted()
```

If you want to preserve the order of your data source then you can use `NSOrderedSet`.

```
let monthListOrdered = NSOrderedSet(array: res.compactMap( {$0.monthName})).array as! [String]
```

However if you want the months in the order they appear on the calender, you need to sort them as dates.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM"
let monthList = Set(res.compactMap( {$0.monthName}))
let sortedMonthList = monthList.sorted(by: { dateFormatter.date(from: $0)! < dateFormatter.date(from: $1)! })
```

**Important Note:** Force-unwrapping has been done because it is obvious from the data source that you will receive only valid months.

Comment: @Laffen why not?

Comment: this code is giving outout, but not in order of monthName, its giving ["August", "December", "November", "October"]..

Comment: yeh..the edited code is working perfectly ,just a query that I have to forcefully wrap into ! [String].. will it affect to my code ` self.monthList = Array(NSOrderedSet(array: res.compactMap( {$0.monthName}))) as! [String]`

Comment: @KiranS as long as you don't change the type of `monthName` from `String`, it shouldn't. You could always go for safely unwrapping with if-let if it bothers you.