# Filter data in less time

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I have 2000 contacts and i want to find duplicates and the filter is taking like 1min to find duplicates.

```
let duplicateArray = contacts.filter { value in 
    contacts.filter({ 
        $0.phoneNumbers.first?.value.value(forKey: "stringValue") as? 
        String ?? "" == value.phoneNumbers.first?.value.value(forKey: 
        "stringValue") as? String ?? "" 
    }).count > 1  
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727618/find-duplicate-elements-in-array-using-swift ?

Comment: You can use `Set`. You have require to confirm `Equatable ` protocol for your custom class.

Comment: i want to fetch both duplicate number eg: let array = [1,2,3,3] so output must be [3,3]

Comment: I'd suggest using Core Data and keeping your contacts in a database. It's super fast for searching & sorting.

Comment: @DavidSteppenbeckPhD i had used CoreData but it takes 45sec just to add 2000 data

Comment: @SiddhantKuldeep I'm surprised it took that long. Were you updating/adding in small batches (groups of ~50 objects) rather than all 2000 at once?

Comment: @DavidSteppenbeckPhD in viewillappear i was adding all 2000 contacts in CoreData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want the duplicated, use a combination of `Dictionary's` **`init(grouping:by:)`**, **`filter(_:)`** and **`flatMap(_:)`**.

**Example:**

```
let arr = [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4]
let result = Dictionary(grouping: arr, by: { $0 }).filter({ $0.1.count > 1 }).flatMap({ $0.value })

print(result) //[2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: this filter is taking 2mins to filter 2000 data

Comment: Are you sure @SiddhantKuldeep? I can run it in 33ms

Comment: @SiddhantKuldeep It isn't. Kindly add the method you're using to calculate the execution time. It is taking somewhere around 30-40ms.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider this array

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,3,2]
```

Using a dictionary, let's count how many times each element appears in the array:

```
var dict : [Int: Int] = [:]

for element in array {
    dict[element, default: 0] += 1
}
```

Now let's construct a new array that contains the elements that appear more than once in the original array:

```
var output = dict.flatMap { (key, value) in
    return Array(repeating: key, count: value == 1 ? 0 : value)
}

print(output)  //[3, 3, 2, 2]
```

Comment: I was doing this same answer but just before you submitted it :p.

Comment: @ShivamGaur maybe next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

A good way to remove duplicates is using the Set(), since a Set can only contain one of each element

```
let duplicates = [1, 2, 3, 3]
let unique = Set(duplicates) // will only contain 1, 2 and 3
```

Comment: but i want output as: [3,3]

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
   func removingDuplicates() -> [Element] {
       var addedDict = [Element: Bool]()

       return filter {
           addedDict.updateValue(true, forKey: $0) == nil
       }
   }

   mutating func removeDuplicates() {
       self = self.removingDuplicates()
   }
}
```